Upload failure - PlatformIO, ST-LINK/V2, Black Pill F411
I am starting to use a black pill V3.1 F411. The IDE is VSC with PlatformIO. I connect with a (genuine, I think) ST-LINK/V2. The connection is made as per the Barnaby Walters article on this.
Basically he describes two ways - powered from the ST-LINK, and self powered. The former uses 5 wires - GND, DIO, CLK, 3V3 (power from ST-LINK) and 3V3 is also fed back to STLINK VAPP pin for power monitoring. The latter just uses 4 wires - GND, DIO, CLK, and 3V3 fed back to STLINK VAPP pin for power monitoring - the board has some other supply.
I’ve been using ST-LINK powered and all was fine, uploading, debugging etc was all good.
But, when I swapped to self powered (the black pill being powered from a 5V0 supply), I cannot connect to upload. A typical error is:
xPack Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0-01004-g9ea7f3d64-dirty (2023-01-30-15:04)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    
http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
debug_level: 1

hla_swd
Error: init mode failed (unable to connect to the target)
in procedure 'program'
** OpenOCD init failed **
shutdown command invoked

*** [upload] Error 1

I have tried various combinations of powering up with boot0 or nrst down, makes no difference. The code is unchanged - upload (and debug) works one way, not the other. I’m not using PA13/14 (CLK and DIO) for anything. The only way I can get it to upload and debug is when powered from the ST-LINK/V2, however, once the code is loaded, the board and app run perfectly well standalone off 5V0/0V.
Pretty much all of it must be OK, or I couldn’t upload and debug when powered from the ST-LINK. The onboard regulator is generating 3.308V, so that all looks good.
A bit stuck here, can anyone advise?

Your questioin requires some clarification. I’ve using self powered and all was fine, uploading, debugging etc was all good. And the next sentence is But, when I swapped to self powered (...), I cannot connect to upload. Mutually contradicting sentences right next to each other.

Yes, mistakenly written, should read: "when powered from the ST-LINK all was fine, when swapped to self-powered, cannot upload". However, moved on since. Added a 22/16 cap on the 5V right next to the black pill module (prototype breadboard, not real PCB yet). Now usually works. Suspect therefore it is/was power/earthing noise. Watching the SWD signals on a scope they look horrible with ringing etc, so probably earthing.

The often overlooked part is the quality of electrical connections, and especially the ground connection. If the signal looked bad, it must have been a really bad connection. Maybe you could connect ground at a different point on PCB. Also, maybe also put a bulk capacitor on the power line? (I have no idea what "22/16 cap" is, it's a weird way to describe a capacitor)
